# Parámetros opcionales en Java

Tags: java

Estoy creando una clase en Java y me encuentro con una serie de funciones que son bastante parecidas, sólo añadiendo un parámetro más que la anterior función, algo como esto (simplificado para demostración):

```
public class miClase {
  public String propiedad1;
  public String propiedad2;
  public String propiedad3;

  // ...

  public void operacion1() {
    propiedad1 = "val1";
    propiedad2 = "val2";
    propiedad3 = "val3";
  }

  public void operacion1(String prop1) {
    propiedad1 = prop1;
    propiedad2 = "val2";
    propiedad3 = "val3";
  }

  public void operacion1(String prop1, String prop2) {
    propiedad1 = prop1;
    propiedad2 = prop2;
    propiedad3 = "val3";
  }

  public void operacion1(String prop1, String prop2, String prop3) {
    propiedad1 = prop1;
    propiedad2 = prop2;
    propiedad3 = prop3;
  }

  // ...

}
```

En otros lenguajes, como por ejemplo PHP, se pueden tener argumentos/parámetros opcionales dándoles un valor por defecto en la definición de la función. ¿Es posible hacer algo similar en Java? ¿Cómo podría hacerse/simularse?

Comment: Java no lo permite. Más info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values

Comment: ¿Se puede simular de algún modo?

Comment: Puedes pasarle un array como parámetro con tus datos dentro, por ejemplo. Luego, en el método, determinas lo que hay en el array. Y **[mira esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994104/5587982)**, parece muy interesante.

Comment: Puedes pasar los tres parámetros y después comparar el valor de cada uno, de esta manera, en la llamada al método tu le asignas los valores

Comment: También la clase **[`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)**   introducida en Java 8 puede ser interesante para tales propósitos.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Los valores default siempre son los mismos?

Comment: @Jorgesys sí, los valores por defecto siempre son iguales

Comment: Me temo que deberás utilizar sobre carga de métodos, o bien la clase Optional

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro sobre carga de métodos u Optional como menciona Cedano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si los valores default son los mismos, los valores únicamente se pueden definir en la clase o la definición de la función, se puede usar "sobrecarga de métodos", esto es una opción:

```
public class miClase {
  public String propiedad1 = "val1";
  public String propiedad2 = "val2";
  public String propiedad3 = "val3";

  public void operacion1() {
    operacion1(propiedad1, propiedad2, propiedad3);
  }

  public void operacion1(String prop1) {
    propiedad1 = prop1;
    operacion1(propiedad1, propiedad2, propiedad3);    
  }

  public void operacion1(String prop1, String prop2) {
    propiedad1 = prop1;
    propiedad2 = prop2;
    operacion1(propiedad1, propiedad2, propiedad3);
  }

  public void operacion1(String prop1, String prop2, String prop3) {
    propiedad1 = prop1;
    propiedad2 = prop2;
    propiedad3 = prop3;
  }

}
```

De esta forma puedes llamar los métodos sobreescribiendo únicamente los valores que definidos al llamar el método deseado :

```
ClaseA a = new ClaseA();
a.operacion1();
a.operacion1("Alvaro");
a.operacion1("Alvaro", "Moderador");
a.operacion1("Alvaro", "Moderador", "StackOverFlow");
```

---

Es lo más común en este caso, usar [sobrecarga de métodos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: Esta es la forma Java de hacer lo que pides Alvaro.

Comment: Una recomendación es que si necesitas soportar más argumentos, puedas crear la sobrecarga con el varargs, pero que dicho método sea el último de toda la cadena de métodos. Esto se debe a cómo trata Java la invocación de métodos por varargs. Aquí una explicación al respecto: [Java method params: var args vs array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25217815/1065197)

Comment: Esto está muy mal. En métodos con menos de tres parámetros no se está asignando el valor por defecto que pide el autor original de la pregunta. Además en el código original las tres variables se inicializan, por defecto, a NULL al construir un objeto de la clase `miClase` lo cual no se respeta en este código. Podemos ver como se manifiestan estos dos errores [aquí](https://ideone.com/n5K6sO).

Comment: Haha @tototita ! "En mètodos de menos de tres parámetros no se esta asignando el valor por defecto", estos valores default estan definidos en la clase. @ "en el código original las tres variables se inicializan, por defecto, a NULL al construir un objeto de la clase miClase lo cual no se respeta en este código", esto es precisamente lo que no desea Alvaro, desea que tengan valores default pero NO null.

Comment: Creo que sería mejor que en lugar de usar atributos `String propiedad1` y demás, sean variables locales. Así reducimos problemas en una aplicación multi hilos donde la misma instancia de la clase se usa en concurrencia y llama a dichos métodos de distinta forma. Es mejor mantener este tipo de clases con el menor estado posible.

Answer (score 2):

Existen varios patrones en Java relacionados con la construcción de objetos que podrías tratar de adaptar a tu problema. En esencia, la problemática es la misma: métodos/constructores con un gran número de parámetros y muy parecidos.

[**Telescoping Constructor**](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/05/telescoping-constructor-antipattern.html#.WbOpgshJbKs)

```
operacion(String prop1, String prop2, String prop3) { ... }   
operacion(String prop1, String prop2) { ... }   
operacion(String prop1) { ... }
```

Con la adaptación de este patrón, cada método reutiliza el anterior (informando null o un valor por defecto para el resto de parámetros), de manera que tan solo has debido darle cuerpo al primero de ellos. 
Lo malo de este patrón para el caso de emplear muchos parámetros (más de 5) es la dificultad de recordar el orden de cada uno de ellos, sobretodo si son todos del mismo tipo.

---

[**Builder Pattern**](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html)

```
OperationBuilder ob = new MiClase.OperationBuilder(POSIBLES_VALORES_OBLIGATORIOS);
ob.prop1(value1).prop2(value2).prop3(value3);
ob.performOperation();
```

Con este patrón tendrías mucha más flexibilidad y el código quedaría mucho más claro e intuitivo. Estamos hablando claro, de muchas opciones a la hora de realizar la operación final.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con argumentos variables, siempre que sean del mismo tipo.

Algo como:

```
public void operacion(String... props){
  if(props!=null){
      switch(props.length){
          case 0:
              propiedad1 = "val1";
              propiedad2 = "val2";
              propiedad3 = "val3";
              break;
          case 1:
              propiedad1 = props[0];
              propiedad2 = "val2";
              propiedad3 = "val3";
              break;
          case 2:
              propiedad1 = props[0];
              propiedad2 = props[1];
              propiedad3 = "val3";
              break;
          case 3:
              propiedad1 = props[0];
              propiedad2 = props[1];
              propiedad3 = props[2];
              break;
      }
    } else {
        propiedad1 = "val1";
        propiedad2 = "val2";
        propiedad3 = "val3";
    }
}
```

De esta forma podras usar el metodo varios parametros de entrada sin necesidad de declarar null los demas.

```
miclase.operacion("datos1");
miclase.operacion("datos1","datos2");
miclase.operacion("datos1","datos2","datos3");
```

Documentacion de Java sobre [los varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Comment: También puedes llamar `operacion(null)` y destruir la funcionalidad.

Comment: Ya esta editada.

Comment: Ahora tiene código duplicado, lo cual implica mal diseño, mayor dificultad en las pruebas y complica el mantenimiento. Algo relativamente sencillo de implementar, usando la herramienta incorrecta, lo vuelve un infierno para futuros devs que deban mantener dicho código.

Answer (score 1):

Crea solo la 3ra, con algunos ajustes:

```
public void operacion1(String prop1, String prop2, String prop3) {
  propiedad1 = (prop1!=null)?prop1:"val1";
  propiedad2 = (prop2!=null)?prop2:"val2";
  propiedad3 = (prop3!=null)?prop3:"val3";
}
```

Al invocar los datos que deben tomar el valor por default los envias en null;

```
operacion1("Julio Cesar",null,null);
```

Comment: Se parece a como sería en JavaScript, pero ¿tengo que llamar a la función con todos los argumentos? ¿o podría hacer algo como `operacion1("Julio Cesar")`?

Comment: Java no lo maneja como javascript por ello debes mandar todos los parametros, de lo contrario desde el IDE te indicaria que esa funcion requiere mas parametros.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar el método para que compare el valor de los parámetros:

```
public class miClase {
  public String propiedad1;
  public String propiedad2;
  public String propiedad3;

  public void operacion(String prop1, String prop2, String prop3) {
       if(prop1 == null) propiedad1 = "val1";
       else propiedad1 = prop1;

       if(prop2 == null) propiedad2 = "val2";
       else propiedad2 = prop2;

       if(prop3 == null) propiedad3 = "val3";
       else propiedad3 = prop3;
  }
}
```

Ahora, desde la llamada tu decides los parámetros que le mandas, por ejemplo:

```
obj.operacion("valorDiferente", null, null);
obj.operacion("valor1", "valor2", null);
obj.operacion(null, null, null);
```

etcétera.

Answer (score 0):

Si queremos ceñirnos a los principios SOLID yo reutilizaría el código ya escrito, aprovechando por completo las otras funciones sin cambiar su significado. El método sin parámetros establece los valores por defecto, el resto de los métodos modifica sólo la propiedad que se le pasa por parámetro :

```
public class miClase {
  public String propiedad1;
  public String propiedad2;
  public String propiedad3;

  // ...

  public void operacion1() {
    propiedad1 = "val1";
    propiedad2 = "val2";
    propiedad3 = "val3";
  }

  public void operacion1(String prop1) {
    operacion1();
    propiedad1 = prop1;
  }

  public void operacion1(String prop1, String prop2) {
    operacion1(prop1);
    propiedad2 = prop2;
  }

  public void operacion1(String prop1, String prop2, String prop3) {
    operacion1(prop1, prop2);
    propiedad3 = prop3;
  }

  // ...

}
```

Answer (score -2):

No, no puedes usar parámetros por defecto en Java. La mejor forma de hacer lo que quieres es tal y como lo has hecho en tu pregunta. Es así como lo hacen en las librerías de Java. Por ejemplo en `String` tenemos, entre otros, estos dos constructores :

> public String(byte[] bytes)
>
> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using
>   the platform's default charset. The length of the new String is a
>   function of the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of
>   the byte array.
>
> public String(byte[] bytes,
>         Charset charset)
>
> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using
>   the specified charset. The length of the new String is a function of
>   the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of the byte
>   array.

Como puedes ver el primero hace lo mismo que el segundo pero usando el charset por defecto.

Una posible alternativa sería utilizar varargs :

```
  public void operacion1(String ... prop) {
    if (prop.length > 3 )
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Maximo de 3 parametros");
    if (prop.length>0)
      propiedad1 = prop[0];
    else
      propiedad1 = "val1";
    if (prop.length>1)
      propiedad2 = prop[1];
    else
      propiedad2 = "val2";
    if (prop.length>2)
      propiedad3 = prop[2];
    else 
      propiedad3 = "val3"; 
  }
```

Pero esto tiene el inconveniente de que si pones mas de 3 parámetros no recibirás un error de compilación, que es lo deseable, sino que tendrás el error en tiempo de ejecución. Por eso en el diseño de las clases standard de Java han preferido la primera alternativa.